# Adding a Method

Tags: c#, list

Is it possible to have a method that can add a whole object with its properties and then call the method inside the main function?

I need to put in action case 3 using the list I provide below. But, I also do not want to put `List<Student> st = new List<Student>()`; both in `WriteToFile()` and `AddStudent()`.

For example, I have that list:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Student> st = new List<Student>();
        Student st1 = new Student(1, "Mike", "Freelancer", 9);
        st1.CalculateSalary();
        Student st2 = new Student(2, "Bob", "CEO", 7);
        st2.CalculateSalary();
        Student st3 = new Student(3, "Tina", "CEO", 3);
        st3.CalculateSalary();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("============================");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Write To File");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Read From File");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Add Student");
            Console.WriteLine("============================");
            answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (answer)
            {
                case 1:
                    WriteToFile(filePath);
                    Console.WriteLine("File Created!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ReadFromFile(filePath);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Add Student");
                    break;
            }
        } while (answer != 4);
   }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why is this question tagged as C++, if it doesn't have anything to do with C++?

Comment: What do you mean by a separate SO?

Comment: Why would you ever put `List<Student> st = new List<Student>();` in either `WriteToFile()` OR `AddStudent()`? One method would presumably write the existing student data to a file, and the other would add a new student to the list. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: It might be helpful to also show your `Student` class, and the methods `WriteToFile()`, and `ReadFromFile()`. It seems strange that you have a Method named `CalculateSalary()` and a property that appears to be something like `JobTitle` on a `Student` class. Those sound more like `Employee` methods and properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, what you can do is create a method that takes in a list of students, gathers information about the new student from the user, and then adds a new student to the list. It would also need to ensure that if the list passed in was null, then it would initialize the list.

I'm guessing at what some of your student properties are. You can change them to match your `Student` class.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets student information from the user and adds a new student to the list
/// </summary>
/// <param name="existingStudents">The list of students to add to</param>
private static void AddStudent(List<Student> existingStudents)
{
    // Initialize the list if it's null
    if (existingStudents == null) existingStudents = new List<Student>();

    int tempInt;

    // Get student information from the user
    Console.WriteLine("Enter new student information");

    do
    {
        Console.Write(" 1. Enter student Id: ");
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tempInt));
    var id = tempInt;

    Console.Write(" 2. Enter student Name: ");
    var name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write(" 3. Enter student Job Title: ");
    var jobTitle = Console.ReadLine();

    do
    {
        Console.Write(" 4. Enter student years of service: ");
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tempInt));
    var yrsOfService = tempInt;

    // Add the new student to the list
    existingStudents.Add(new Student(id, name, jobTitle, yrsOfService));
}
```

Then you can just call this from your main method like:

```
case 3:
    AddStudent(st);
    break;
```

Note that in the beginning of your `Main` method, you never add the hard-coded students to your list. After you create your students, you may want to add something like:

```
st.Add(st1);
st.Add(st2);
st.Add(st3);
```

Comment: Thanks you. I have one more question. I would like to read the element from a file and when I read them automatically to fill the list with the data from the file. I tried that but it did not work:          public static void showStudents(List<Student> existingStudents, string filePath)
        {
             ReadFromFile(filePath);
             foreach (Student stud in existingStudents)
             {
                // existingStudents.Add(new Student(stud.id, stud.Name, stud.Position, stud.Internship));
                 Console.WriteLine(stud.ToString());
             }
        }

Comment: Here is the ReadFromFile function:          public static void ReadFromFile(string filePath)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will post it separately.